# Selenium. Как сократить постоянное повторение FindElement

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Задача: заполнение формы на сайте с помощью Selenium язык C#
Проблема: уродливый вид кода из-за постоянных повторений driver.FindElement()
Есть ли возможность сократить количество строк?
Код:

```
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.symphonicms.com/release/create");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("upcquestion")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("subformBasics[Name]")).SendKeys(TestText);
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("subformBasics[isCompilation]")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("select2-subformBasics-TracksQty-container")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[role='textbox'")).SendKeys(TestNum + Keys.Enter);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("select2-subformBasics-MainGenreId-container")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[role='textbox'")).SendKeys(TestNum + Keys.Enter);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("select2-subformBasics-GenreId-container")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[role='textbox'")).SendKeys(TestNum + Keys.Enter);
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("subformBasics[CLine]")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("subformBasics[PLine]")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("subformBasics[PLine]")).SendKeys(TestText);
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("subformBasics[PLine]")).SendKeys(TestText);
```

Comment: Нет, такой возможности нет. И 13 строк - это немного. Вынесите в отдельный метод, если в основном коде оно мешает.

Comment: Создайте обертку над этим всем в виде простых методов. Например `new FormBuilder().AddName("Имя").IsCompilation()...;`, сами однотипные строки также переделайте в метод обертку (например `public void ClickElement(this IWebDriver driver, string element) => driver.FindElement(By.Name(element)).Click();` и дальше просто вызывайте как `diver.ClickElement("subformBasics[isCompilation]")`, вот вам еще один способ улучшения вида. Ну а вообще, самый лучший способ - отказаться от селениума в пользу простых HTTP запросов, ведь форма на сайте, это отправка простого класса на определенный адрес.

Comment: Почитайте про PageObject, и осуществите общую логику хода действий как предложил @EvgeniyZ, так код будет выглядеть намного лучше, чем он есть сейчас, ДЕКОМПОЗИРУЙТЕ